# How to create fixed column width table inside a document using docx

Tags: angular, docx

I am using docx npm to create a small report (word document) in angular 6.
I need to have a table with fixed column width so that whatever text is written inside it, it should get wrapped within the cell. 
I have tried several options but unable to achieve this.
Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Show us what you tried? make a stackblitz ?

Comment: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayz14c) here is my stackblitz link. i want to divide the table in 50:50 column width. But i am not getting the correct options for this. if you edit the document and try to add some text in one of the cell, it will change  the column width automatically which is not desired in my case.

Comment: It seems that its an open issue with docx.

Comment: Okay thanks. I might be switching the npm to docx-templates which can handle complex documentation.